# Who was Hagar's (Avraham's maid/wife) grandfather?

Tags: genealogy, abraham

Who was Hagar's (Avraham's maid/wife) grandfather? I know there is a source somewhere for this but I am baffled as to where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Targum Pseudo-Jonathan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Targum_Pseudo-Jonathan) to Parashat Lekh L'kha (16:5) refers to her as the daughter of Pharaoh who was the son of Nimrod.

> וְלָא נִצְטַרָךְ לִבְנָהָא דְהָגָר בְּרַת פַּרְעֹה בַּר נִמְרוֹד דְטַלְקָךְ לְאַתּוּנָא דְנוּרָא

Comment: This identification of Hagar as the daughter of Pharoh is found in early Rabbinic works, such as Genesis Rabba (45) and in [Muslim works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagar_in_Islam) as well.

Comment: The identification of Hagar with Pharaoh is found in the [Genesis Apocryphon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genesis_Apocryphon), a first century Dead Sea Scroll, as well, although it does not state explicitly that she was his daughter; just that he gave her to Abraham. || According to [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=piqAAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA111&lpg=PA111&dq=hagar+nimrod&source=bl&ots=kf47lUuJdv&sig=hNSUhTMYCeZNmvxRxwx6U2Enz8U&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjx-KG4q6zQAhUm2IMKHRVrAB0Q6AEIKjAD#v=onepage&q=hagar%20nimrod&f=false) Islamic sources identify her as the daughter of Nimrod. (no source listed).

Comment: I believe the source you mentioned infinitely dwarfs the Islamic sources in terms of authenticity and reliability.

Comment: @Elcho The Targum Pseudo Jonathan shows Islamic influence. Whether it was first compiled after Islam, or whether these are later additions is debatable. The reason I even looked for Islamic sources, is that being that this was a strange idea that didn't seem to be present anywhere else in Jewish literature, I guessed (correctly, apparently) that it would appear in Islamic literature. || Its kind of ironic to refer to a work with Pseudo in the title as authentic, and I don't know why it is necessarily reliable...